# How to change the default django project directory in linode

Tags: django, linode

I want to deploy a django application using linode. In the /var/www directory in my linode server, there is a  default django application named, DjangoApp. I dont want to use this default application to deploy my app so I have cloned my django project into the same directory but linode only listens to the default project. Please how do i make linode listen to my new project instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you used Linode's One-Click deployment to create your Linode server, then you should check the crontabs on the machine by running `crontab -l`. The One-Click Django app uses the Django's `runserver` web server. You should see a cron that runs the `runserver`, like the following:

```
@reboot cd /var/www/DjangoApp && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

If you want to change it, you can run `crontab -e` to edit your crons and change the path `/var/www/DjangoApp/` to your desired location. Please also note that runserver is not designed for production so you may want to eventually run your app on web servers like Apache or NGNIX, using uWSGI.